# TCP/IP communication between Hyper-V host and guests

Tags: networking, hyper-v, tcpip

This may be a simple one. :)

I have a simple Hyper-V setup with a few guest os running. The host has 1 physical network adapter with a static IP assigned to it. The guests have network adapters assigned to "Internet" (Hyper-V network) which is bound to the physical host network adapter (Hyper-V "External" connection type).

I am not able to communicate (ping or anything else) between guests and host. I've checked firewall and it seems fine (ports open from anywhere still don't work). I'm trying to communicate with the hosts IP assigned to the same physical interface that the guests are sharing. Guests can communicate between them just fine.

I can't seem to find any relevant setting (I might just be missing it).

**So my questions: How do I fix it so host and guests can communicate?**

Answer (score 1):

When you set up a virtual network for the guest machines to use, there's a checkbox for allowing the host to share the network. Did you enable this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [link](http://www.virtuatopia.com/index.php/Understanding_and_Configuring_Hyper-V_Virtual_Networks) to an article going over Hyper-V networking.  Are both the host and the guests on the same network?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple links I've kept around on configuring Hyper-V Networking.

http://tekktips.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!3C3690998D3204D7!494.entry

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc816585(WS.10).aspx

Hope these help.